# ¿Por qué pdfbox no puede leer un .pdf ?

Tags: java, eclipse, pdfbox2.0

Estoy usando la librería de pdfbox para extracción de información de pdfs pero me he topado que algunos pdfs no me regresa nada de información, no sé cuál será el problema

Uso este codigo para la lectura de un pdf:

cLASE DatosCASA datoscas = new DatosCASA ()
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        File file = new File("C:\COPSIS\Archivos_pdf\CASA.pdf");
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new RandomAccessFile(file, "r")); // update for PDFBox V 2.0

```
    parser.parse();
    COSDocument cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    PDDocument pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
        pdfStripper.setEndPage(1);

///////////////////////////////

pdfStripper.setSortByPosition(true);

/////////////////////
pdfStripper.setParagraphStart("@@@");
         //pdfStripper.setParagraphEnd(">");
        pdfStripper.setWordSeparator("###");

////////////////

String Text = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);

////////

Imprime el texto de pdf en cosola
 System.out.println(Text);

////////////////

pdDoc.close();

Comment: Hola Adan, no olvides formular tu pregunta en base a [ask] para que sea bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas la solución a tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar lo que has intentado? Así será más fácil puntualizar tu problema y ayudarte.